# Solution explorer menu in Visual Studio 2015 is missing jspm packages and config.js

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, configuration-files, aurelia, jspm

I'm following an aurelia tutorial with **Visual Studio 2015** and **ASP.NET core** where I installed NPM and run JSPM init, but after successfully creating all the files I can't find the **jspm packages** or **config.js** file in my **Solution explorer.**

**UPDATE 1** The hidden folders and files are now showing up, but I have to right click on the main directory and chose the option to **add to existing item.** As you can see from the image I have a lot of files and folders, how can I speed up the process? Is there a way to just add all files to the project at the same time instead of manually?
[image]

**Note:** The config.js and jspm packages are on my physical directory so I know they exist, but **how can I make them show up on my solution explorer menu?**

**STEPS:**
I opened cmd prompt and entered: `jspm init`  + `npm install jspm --save-dev` and selected yes on everything except on the configuration file part I entered: `wwwroot` and enter yes on everything, then selected babel.

Please let me know what I should do to make the files show up on the solution explorer or at least point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Originally VS projects did not automatically include new files that were added to the Project directory manually outside of Visual Studio.

However, I find that with VS2015 Update 3 and a new AspNet Core project they do "automagically" show up.

Not sure if maybe you're on a slightly older build, etc. but you could try the older approach as follows:

Select the Project in the Project Explorer (you currently have a solution-level item selected in that screenshot) and then you will see a new icon appear in the row of icons across the top of the Solution Explorer. This is the "Show All Files" icon/button.

Clicking it will show items that are in the physical directory but are not part of the VS Project. You should be able to right-click the file an choose include in project (or at least you used to be able to do this in older projects, etc. as stated).

Comment: I'm still having issues adding all the folders and files at the same time, I can only do one by one manually by choosing add existing item, note: there is no include in project option in my VS2015 Community. Check out my above edited question.